# Passing StringVar object from Entry to Label within functions in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Hi I've been struggling to get this to work, each time i change something I receive another error. I've been trying to create an entry box with a function and then get the variable from the entry box into a label, created by a button press. When I tried to do this often this error came up.

`TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

I then put self in in the method brackets.

`command = lambda: x.myFunc(self.my_variable.get(self))`

Then another error, which I'm not sure how to sort out.

```
AttributeError: 'My_Class' object has no attribute '_tk'
```

Here's the full code, I'm new to classes and `self`, so any corrections are welcome.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

class My_Class:
    def start(self):
        self.root=Tk()
        self.my_variable=StringVar
        self.entry_box=Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.my_variable)
        self.entry_box.pack()
        self.button=Button(self.root,text="Pass variable now",
         command=lambda:x.myFunc(self.my_variable.get(self)))
        self.button.pack()

def myFunc(self,my_variable):
    self.lab=Label(self.root,text=self.my_variable)
    self.lab.pack()

x=My_Class()
x.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to create a `StringVar` object:

```
text = StringVar() # note additional ()
```

Can you explain me what `x` is in the following statement:

```
lambda: x.myFunc(self.my_variable.get(self))
```

`x` is not visible inside the class, because it's declared outside the class.

`myFunc` is not indented correctly: you should indent it like the `__init__` method.

I really recommend you to watch some tutorials on OOP before proceeding. You are basically trying to guess how OOP works.

Comment: I will do now thanks for that, I didn't realize quite how complex it was. the 'x 'was meant  as part of the My_Class class I hadn't realized what that was meant to do. Thanks for helping, lots of tutorials are needed!

Answer (score 1):

If you make `myFunc` A method if the class (which you might be trying to do; it's hard to know because your indentation is wrong), you don't have to pass anything to `myFunc`. That function has access to everything in the class, so it can get what it needs, when it needs it. That lets you eliminate the use of `lambda`, which helps reduce complexity.

Also, you normally don't need a `StringVar` at all, it's just one more thing to keep track of. However, if you really need the label and entry to show exactly the same data, have them share the same textvariable and the text is updated automatically without you having to call a function, or get the value from the widget, or set the value n the label.

Here's an example without using `StringVar`:

```
class My_Class:
    def start(self): 
        ...
        self.entry_box = Entry(self.root)
        self.button = Button(..., command = self.myFunc)
        ...

    def myFunc(self):
        s = self.entry_box.get()
        self.lab = Label(..., text = s)
        ...
```